Preventing Node Deletion with Criteria: Issues with Bulk Operations
I am using hook_node_predelete() function  in my Drupal module to prevent node deletion based on certain criteria. The logic works well for individual node deletions, but I'm facing issues with bulk operations from the /admin/content page.
Here’s the code I’ve written:
/**
 * Implements hook_node_predelete().
 */
function mymodule_node_predelete(Node $node) {
  // Check if the node meets the condition.
  $enabler = \Drupal::service('mycondition.enabler');
  if ($enabler->isEnabled($node)) {
    // Set a message for the user.
    \Drupal::messenger()->addError(t('You cannot delete this node because the condition is not met.'));
    $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse(\Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.edit_form', ['node' => $node->id()])->toString());
    $response->send();
    exit();
  }
}

The issue arises when I try to delete multiple nodes at once. If any of the selected nodes match the criteria, the process exits without deleting the others.
What I would like to achieve is:
Skip nodes that match the criteria: If a node is not allowed to be deleted, it should simply be skipped in the bulk operation.
Any suggestions on how to modify my implementation to achieve this functionality would be greatly appreciated!

You should filter out the nodes that you don’t want to be deleted in the View itself - sending a response in the middle of the page build will always have unexpected results. It physically works, but you shouldn’t consider it to be “supported” as such. It could also never work in the context you’re describing; once you send a response, that’s it, request over

This question is similar to: How do I prevent a Node from being deleted?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

^ that other question may not be precisely the same, as you want delete requests to be silently ignored.

An access hook for the “delete” op might make more sense here. I don’t know how bulk operations react to being told to perform a forbidden op on an entity. With any luck the batch will continue and failures will result in messages.
